# have_comments not true for logged out visitors?

Tags: comments

For some strange reason, comments aren't being displayed when a user is *not* logged in. I've done some extensive experimenting with comments.php without any success. Here's a reference to the example page:

http://gycweb.org/by-this-will-all-men-know/

If you are logged in, you would see 3 comments. If you are not logged in, nothing but the form. Also, to add to the mystery, when "editing" the post from within the admin and clicking "show comments", it tries and is not able to load the comments.

It appears that the "have_comments" conditional is failing for logged out users. I've also tried getting wp_list_comments to return the list with no success.

I've checked for plugin conflicts and nothing obvious yet. Have any of you run into this? Any obvious answers?

Comment: Can you post your `comments.php` template file code?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/H5EeJrEp

Comment: And can you also post `single.php` and `functions.php`?

Comment: Single.php, here: http://pastebin.com/nvtFZ0Wb and the relevant portion of the functions file here: http://pastebin.com/mZcU10f5

Comment: Um,oops... sorry for editing your question; thought I was editing an answer. Want me to pull that down into a comment?

Comment: No problem, Chip! Do go ahead and pull them down into a comment, if you would. -  I do have 2 plugins affecting registration, "Members" and "Register Plus Redux". Is there anyway to check and see what filters are in action? I will go carefully through the plugins and see if I can find a culprit.

Comment: I don't see anything in `comments.php`, `single.php`, or your comment callback in `functions.php`. Next questions: 1. Do you have any filters on comments? 2. Do you have any Plugins that might be interacting/interfering with comments? 3. Do you have any Plugins that are membership/registration/login related?

Comment: Can you try disabling those Plugins, and see if the problem persists?

Comment: According to your original question, "If you are logged in, you would see 3 comments. If you are not logged in, nothing but the form.... It appears that the "have_comments" conditional is failing for logged out users." Is your intention to show comments for all users, both logged in and out?

Comment: Hey, Jonathan Wold, have you solved your problem? I've got the same case in a MultiSite installation and it's driving me crazy. have_comments() returns false, yet I can't find a plugin that's messing with the comments. Further more, I found out that when a logged out user post a comment, immediately all previous comments "magically" appear, together with the one, awaiting moderation... Another clue - in Codex is written, that it checks for comments in the results of the global $wp_query. Any reason to have it reset on user not logged in?

Comment: My guess: You are using `query_posts()` somewhere, maybe in a widget/sidebar. This affects the main query.

Comment: @toscho - You were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toscho was right. I wound up having a query that was getting in the way. It took a bit of troubleshooting to figure out, but I nailed it.

If you run into similar issues, look carefully for any custom queries you may have on the template and make sure that you've wrapped them up properly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your web-server user does not have permissions to create new files. I believe that WordPress caches comments on pages and posts for not logged users, so that only authenticated users get fresh comments list. When logged out user inputs a comment, the list gets updated with his comment too, which brings them the whole list (I tried that on my WP instance and yours, it works that way). Otherwise WP tries to get comments from a file, that it couldn't create beforehand, resulting in have_comments() returning false.

So, if you provide write permissions for www-data or whatever else is called your web-server user, you will forget for the problem.

The whole thing is still a theory, as I won't have access to my installation for about 10 days, but I strongly believe that this is the solution.

Answer (score -1):

According to your original question, "If you are logged in, you would see 3 comments. If you are not logged in, nothing but the form.... It appears that the "have_comments" conditional is failing for logged out users."

Is your intention to show comments for all users, both logged in and out?

If you want comments to show for logged out users, then you need to remove this:

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) : ?>
            <p class="nopassword"><?php _e( 'This post is password protected. Enter the password to view any comments.', 'twentyten' ); ?></p>
        </div><!-- #comments -->
```

Comment: That's absolutely not true. "Logged-in users" != "post password required". The appropriate conditional would be `is_user_logged_in()`, not `post_password_required()`.

Comment: I see what you mean there. Another possibility is either the file is corrupted or the permission is wrong. Unless he has something else on other files controlling comment that he's not aware of.

Comment: My best guess at this point is that it's one of the two Plugins he referenced.

Comment: you're probably right, and most likely the gyc_blog_comments function. perhaps function_exists did not recognize it, and stop to interpret the rest.